# mysql Main and detail tables with detail data being "joined"

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Main and detail with are linked togeather. The output would be somethink like this:

```
Records found: 8 
mail.field  detail.Field
A               x
A               y
A               z
B               i
B               j
C               l
C               m
C               n
```

Is it possible to "concat" all detail-Valus to geht this result

```
Records found: 3

A       x+y+z
B       i+j
C       l+m+m
```

Comment: If you have 2 tables please show them clearly as 2 tables and show the complete set of columns on both cases, or at least show the columns you are interested in and the columns that connect the 2 tables

Answer (score 3):

You can use `group_concat()`

```
select main_field, group_concat(detail.Field order by detail.Field SEPARATOR '+')
from tablename
group by main_field
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select main_field, group_concat(detail.Field order by detail.Field SEPARATOR '+')
from tablename
JOIN .....
group by main_field
```